# Assertion in [AfterStep] doesn't set ScenarioContext.Current.TestError

Tags: .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In `[AfterStep]` I fail test:

```
[AfterStep]
public void StopOnUnexpectedBrowserLogs()
{
    Assert.Fail("sth sth");
}
```

and then in `[AfterScenario]` I want to act when test is failed:

```
[AfterScenario]
public void AfterScenario()
    if (ScenarioContext.Current.TestError != null)
    {
       DoSomething();
    }
}
```

however `ScenarioContext.Current.TestErrors` is always null in that case. How can I force something to be assigned there in `[AfterStep]` method?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find solution but only workaround. I tested that any failing asserion in method annotated by `[AfterScenario]` doesn't set `TestError` property. `TestError` property is assigned only if asserion fails in `Then,When,Given` etc. annotated methods.
Thus I just added a simple `public bool SthBadHappened {get;set;}` property that I use as my `TestError` property.